# Magento 2.3.2 strings not translating

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am not able to figure out why some of the strings which I input in my i18 > bg_BG.csv are not translating. I will give a small example with Qty.

```
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_Catalog
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_AdvancedCheckout
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_CatalogInventory
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_Checkout
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_Customer
Qty,Количество,module,Magento_GiftRegistry
```

These are the occurrences in my translation file for Qty, neither of them work. I cannot understand am I doing something wrong. I've cleared cache, deployed static files, changed from production to developer. Some of the strings in the file are translated and others not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your csv here in this path in your custom theme..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/bg_BG.csv

And after adding that CSV here, Please run below commands once..

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f bg_BG
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After that please clear your Browser's cache, otherwise please check your translated string in Private window.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have the file exactly there and I am applying all the steps you've provided me with but the result is the same. Some of the strings are translated some are not. I want to mention that I have child theme. The translation file is located there and the child theme is applied as a default theme if this is making any difference.

Comment: Child theme means you have replicated Luma theme as a parent and you have created your custom theme. Am I Right here?

Comment: Yes exactly, I cannot understand what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you please go to **pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/** directory ?

And check if there is any csv file available then please remove that once and run deploy command and then check.

Hope that will work then..

Comment: Hey yes I have csv file there when I delete it and deploy the content the file is generated with the same strings as before tried it a few times everything in there is exactly the same...

Comment: Can you please try to add above 4 lines which you have mentioned in your question in csv format there and clear cache and check if that if working with that? If No then please add Qty and it's translated text with double quotes and run all commands.

Comment: Just tried it and whenever I run the commands and open the same file all the added records are deleted. The file is like set to the original with none of the new records there...

Comment: Can you please give me your full file path?

Comment: This is the exact path -> pub/static/frontend/vendorTheme/myThemeHere/bg_BG/i18n/bg_BG.csv

Comment: Can you please add this line there in your pub static file in the last? **"Qty","Количество"**

Comment: Add with double quotes and then clear you browser cache or check in private window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100073/discussion-between-h3k-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: Check the `pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/bg_BG/js-translation.json` file and see if the `"Qty"` string is in there. If it is try deleting the `mage-translation-storage` in your browser's local storage

Comment: Is above solution helpful to you ?